# Scorecard display of types of AdWord Conversions without using a filter

Tags: google-ads-api, looker-studio

I'm trying to filter my scorecard display of Adword Conversions by Conversion category by using a calculated field instead of a filter. I've tried the following but was unsuccessful. Suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
Conversions * MAX(CASE
    WHEN Segment Conversion Type ID = 248974699 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END )
```

If you're wondering why I don't want to just use a filter, I want to then use this custom field to do further calculations for cost, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because the ID is a dimension and conversions is a metric, and you can't use both in a calculated field. Try splitting them out, make one that calculates the number of that ID, then create a second metric that multiples it by conversions.

Comment: Thank Litmon.

When I do
max(CASE WHEN Segment Conversion Type ID = 248974699 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

it returns 1.

When I do
count(CASE WHEN Segment Conversion Type ID = 248974699 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

it returns 3

I know that the number should be 5, any idea which calculation to do?

Comment: Try sum(case when...) and see what that gets you.